# Upload audio (music files) from iphone to server

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am building an app to upload images/videos/audios from iPhone4 to server. I am done with the image and video part but is stuck with audio uploads. I found out that audios are stored in the in-built iPod app instead of the library where images and videos are saved.

I found out that the path for audio is /var/root/Media/iTunes_Control/Music.

Please let me know how can upload the audio from this path to server.

Thanks in advance for any help.